# Extract substring from ComboBox selected Item and insert it on top of existing text in Multiline field Python

Tags: python, list, combobox, multiline, pysimplegui

Dears,

Just to be straighforward here, I'm having a list of items in ComboBox Field.
My query is : I want Each time I select one item from that list it will append one line in Mulitiline field with substring of that line. , Let's say the code will append **"n Characters"** string in the Multiline field on top of existing text.

Example :

**INPUT ( From ComboBox):**

```
List = [
   (01). Item1
   (02). Item2
   (03). Item3
   ....
```

**OUTPUT (To Multiline ):**, in case I select 2 items from the list I should end up with the following :

```
   (01).
   (02).
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do nor what is the problem. Are you using a GUI framework for your "ComboBox Field" ? (web, Qt, Tkinter, ...) Would you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with clear (code) expectations ?

Comment: Thanks @Lenormju, In fact issue is easy , probably I didn't explain it well,it's a mapping between input fields in PySimpleGUI, where I need to extract substring from another Input field ( automatic way).....and actually I solve it following one of topics by Tkinter. Could you please help on this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74328723/replacing-consonants-and-vowels-in-a-string-python-pysimplegui 
Thanks

Comment: I added the PySimpleGUI to your question's tag. And it would have been better if you included it in your question intially. As to your problem, you want that, depending on the combobox' choices that are selected, these lines are added to a corresponding multiline label ? Did I understood correctly ? But what about the "substring" ? You did not explain at all what it should be.

Comment: Thanks for updating the same. Let me explain more just by example : suppose I write 99Python in one input field, i want to have at the output only first 2 strings , which I should have in my case : 99 , Is it clear now? and as I told you it's already fixed.

Comment: It's not clear because there seems to be something missing in your message : `i want to have at the output only first 2 strings , which I should have in my case : 99 , Is it clear now?`. Anyway, if your other (linked) question is solving your problem, we may close this one.

Comment: Yes, this one we can close it.